# Redefinition Overriding in Java

Tags: java, overriding

We got the following exercice in our last exam, and I don't understand the right answers except the 1st one.

Here is it:

```
public class Gran {
   private int x;
   public Gran() { this.x = 68; }
   public int age() { this.x = this.x+1; return this.x; }
   @Override
   public String toString() { return "Gran " + age(); }
}

public class Dad extends Gran {
   private int x;
   public Dad() { this.x = 41; }
   @Override
   public String toString() { return "Dad " + age(); }
}

public class Bro extends Dad {
   private int x;
   public Bro() { this.x = 21; }
   @Override
   public int age() { System.out.print("Bro "); return x; }
}

public class Sis extends Dad {
   private int x;
   public Sis() { this.x = 17; }
   @Override
   public int age() { System.out.print("Sis "); return super.age() - x;                }
   @Override
   public String toString() { return "Sis " + super.toString(); }
}
```

What would be the correct print-outs if we call this:

```
Gran[] family = new Gran[] {new Gran(), new Dad(), new Bro(), new Sis()};
for (Gran member : family) System.out.println(member.toString());
```

It would be really helpful for me, if you tell me the logic behind the right answers.. I got really confused when I checked them!

Comment: **Did you run it and see for yourself?**

Comment: He is looking for the logic. Running the program will most likely not help enough.

Comment: Use the debugger and step through the code. This will help a lot in understanding.

Comment: The example is misleading at best, having class Sis that extends Dad is kinda weird ;P

Comment: This example of inheritance is rather bad because each subclass introduces its own new, shadowed version of the private field `x`.

Comment: Interestingly,Bro doesnt have a toString. Was this a typo or is it the way it is?

Comment: That's a strange family. I understand that every brother may eventually become a dad, even a grandpa. But I doubt that any sister will ever become one of these.

Comment: I didn't see any Overloading in your examples. Overloading is different with Overriding & Inheritance

Comment: sorry @Loc it's overriding you're right! 
at-Hirak it doesnt have a toString and it is the way it should be..
at-WojciechPtak yeah.. but what should we do? the problem to solve here is the overriding story :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1). 
Especially Example 8.4.8.1-1. Overriding:

```
class Point {
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    void move(int dx, int dy) { x += dx; y += dy; }
}
class SlowPoint extends Point {
    int xLimit, yLimit;
    void move(int dx, int dy) {
        super.move(limit(dx, xLimit), limit(dy, yLimit));
    }
    static int limit(int d, int limit) {
        return d > limit ? limit : d < -limit ? -limit : d;
    }
}
```

The caption says:

> Here, the class SlowPoint overrides the declarations of method move of class Point with its own move method, which limits the distance that the point can move on each invocation of the method. When the move method is invoked for an instance of class SlowPoint, ***the overriding definition in class SlowPoint will always be called, even if the reference to the SlowPoint object is taken from a variable whose type is Point.***

So with that in consideration, lets look at your example.

The hierarchy is: 
`Dad` is a `Gran` 
`Bro` is a `Dad` 
`Sis` is a `Dad`

The declared type of all of the objects is `Gran` because of the line `Gran[] family = new Gran[] {new Gran(), new Dad(), new Bro(), new Sis()};` That is the same as saying that ***the reference to each of the objects in the array are taken from a variable whose type is*** `Gran`.

Now you will call `toString()` on each of the elements in the `family` array. The first is `Gran.toString()`. When that object was created its `x` variable was initialized to `68`. So the `Gran.toString()` method will build a `String` that is first `"Gran"` then call the `age()` method which increments `x` by one then returns the value of `x` which is `69` at this point. The `+` operator implicitly creates a new `String` that coerces the `int` to a `String` giving a `String` `"Gran 69"`.

Next `Dad.toString` is very similar to `Gran`. Notice that it starts with the `String` `"Dad"` then calls `age()` which is inherited from `Gran`. So the output should be `"Dad 69"`. The trick here is that the `x` variable is `private` scope, so the `x` in `Dad` is a different `x` then in `Gran`. That is the same for all of the classes.

For `Bro`, this class is a `Dad`, and `Dad` is a `Gran`. There is no overridden `toString` here so `Dad.toString()` gets used. That makes a String `"Dad"` then calls `Bro.age()` this prints `"Bro"` then returns the `x` from `Bro` to create a new `String` `"Dad 21"`. The line is will look like `"Bro Dad 21"` because the print of `"Bro"` happens before the print of `"Dad 21"`.

As for `Sis` this one is the toughest one. You should take everything from above and convince your self of how Overriding and scoping works. Good luck! I hope this helps.

Comment: For Sis should be “Sis Sis Dad 52“ but i still confused why not "Sis Dad Sis 52“ anyway I am thankful for the logic.

Comment: So the trick is in `Sis.age()` the call to `System.out.println("Sis ")` happens before the `String` is constructed for the `Sis.toString()` method. So you get `Sis ` on the terminal, then the print of the `String` that is returned by `Sis.toString()` happens. That prints `Sis Dad 52`. The order of calls is `Sis.toString()`, `Dad.toString()`, `Sis.age()`, print `Sis`, `Gran.age()`, print the `String` returned by `Sis.toString()`. Hope it helps, If you would like to accept the answer that would be great! Thanks!